# No issuer certificate

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I have an exception : `No issuer certificate for certificate in certification path found.`

```
PkixBuilderParameters builderParams = new PkixBuilderParameters(rootCerts, holder);
builderParams.IsRevocationEnabled = false;
X509CollectionStoreParameters intermediateStoreParameters =
                new X509CollectionStoreParameters(intermediateCerts);
builderParams.AddStore(X509StoreFactory.Create("Certificate/Collection", 
                intermediateStoreParameters));
PkixCertPathBuilderResult result = 
                builder.Build(builderParams); // exception in this line
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the certificate that you are using has no issuing (Root CA) certificate that it can chain to. All certificates are issued (and chain up) to some other certificate. The system could not find the cert that this particular cert was issued by, can hence can't verify it.

If this is a self-signed cert, did you install the root cert on your machine that issued this one?